# PHP : Create PDF from html with 400-500 pages

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, wkhtmltopdf

I converted html to PDF file which contains 400-500 pages using [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/). But getting undesirable spaces after each 4 rows in table. How to overcome this issue ? HTML is looks fine but [PDF](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/s3healthians/barcodes/2016/12/1482303326.pdf) has spaces.

I use following things to create PDF.

1. PHP =>
   exec('/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf temp.html temp.pdf 2>&1', $output);
2. Style in HTML :

> @media all { table { empty-cells: hide !important;}  tr {
>   page-break:avoid; page-break-inside: avoid; empty-cells:hide;
>   margin:0px; padding:0px;}  .pgBrk { page-break-after: always
>   !important; page-break-inside:avoid !important;}  tr.json-array-table
>   { page-break-inside: avoid !important;}

Please suggest.

Comment: Maybe the cells from the tables are empty!? `empty-cells:hide;`

Comment: No, I have removed this but still facing same issue. I use main table->tr->td->inner table->tr->td and close all tags respectively. Use blank td and tr for space among them with style="border:none;".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this using [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) library. [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org) is fast execution but less customization. TCPDF supports customization and a lot of key features when you work with the creation of PDF files. We can checkout BEST library in php [here](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/226/top-5-best-open-source-pdf-generation-libraries-for-php) .